# How to calculate only nth digit of Pi?

Tags: java, math

I'm using the BBP formula for nth digit of Pi. The normal BBP formula calculates Pi for a certain amount of digits of Pi. I'm trying to get the value of one digit of Pi. There's a section of the Wikipedia BBP formula website on how to get nth digit of Pi. This section is this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bailey%E2%80%93Borwein%E2%80%93Plouffe_formula#BBP_digit-extraction_algorithm_for_%CF%80). So I made a program in Java to calculate nth digit of Pi using my interpretation of the BBP formula for calculating nth digit which is this picture:

[Formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDU7v.png)

Here's the code for my java program. Please let me know if there is a mistake in my formula or java code for calculating the nth digit of Pi because I'm not getting the right answer. For eg)

```
Which decimal digit of Pi do you want? 1
3.0024718637216376E116
C:\Users\matth\Documents>java NthDigitOfPi
Which decimal digit of Pi do you want? 2
9.224189345124711E114
```

```
import java.io.Console;
public class NthDigitOfPi {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Which decimal digit of Pi do you want? ");
        String line = System.console().readLine();
        double n = Double.parseDouble(line);
        double y = 0.0;
        for (double k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            y = y + ((Math.pow(16, (n - k))) % (8 * k + 1)) / (8 * k + 1);
        }
        double z = 0;
        for (double k = (n + 1); k <= 100; k++) {
            z = z + ((Math.pow(16, (100 - k))) / ((8 * k) + 1));
        }
        y = y + z;
        y = 4 * y;

        double y2 = 0;
        for (double k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            y2 = y2 + ((Math.pow(16, (n - k))) % (8 * k + 4)) / (8 * k + 4);
        }
        z = 0;
        for (double k = (n + 1); k <= 100; k++) {
            z = z + ((Math.pow(16, (100 - k))) / ((8 * k) + 4));
        }
        y2 = y2 + z;
        y2 = 2 * y2;
        y = y - y2;

        double y3 = 0;
        for (double k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            y3 = y3 + ((Math.pow(16, (n - k))) % (8 * k + 5)) / (8 * k + 5);
        }
        z = 0;
        for (double k = (n + 1); k <= 100; k++) {
            z = z + ((Math.pow(16, (100 - k))) / ((8 * k) + 5));
        }
        y3 = y3 + z;
        y = y - y3;

        double y4 = 0;
        for (double k = 0; k <= n; k++) {
            y4 = y4 + ((Math.pow(16, (n - k))) % (8 * k + 6)) / (8 * k + 6);
        }
        z = 0;
        for (double k = (n + 1); k <= 100; k++) {
            z = z + ((Math.pow(16, (100 - k))) / ((8 * k) + 1));
        }
        y4 = y4 + z;
        y = y - y4;

        System.out.print(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please give us a specific digit that is not being calculated correctly.

Comment: if you use Math.pow you'll be limited to double's precision

Comment: This formula generates **hexa**decimal digits. How are you planning to convert these to decimal? Also, see [Modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation). Bottom line is `double`s don't have enough precision to store the lower digits of any significant power of 16.

Comment: For eg) I enter 2 for n and get 9.2241

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to your question, or a solution to the problems in your code, but a practical way to get the `nth` digit in Pi in Java would be to just substring `Math.PI`:

```
public char nPi(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index > 15) return '';

    String pi = String.valueOf(Math.PI).replace(".", "");
    char nDigit = pi.charAt(index);

    return nDigit;
}
```

Note: This limits PI to around 16 digits.  But, unless you are doing some very fine precision math, this option might be useful for you.

Comment: I'm trying to make a Pi generator program with no limit for decimal places. Java doesn't show more than about 15 digits for variables so I need to calculate each number of decimal place for Pi in order to generate many digits. I'm making a Pi generator program for any number of places because I'm trying to make a pi generator website where you specify the number of decimal places you want for Pi.

Comment: This method is limited to only as many digits as are found in Math.PI (i.e. not many).

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a combination of @tim Biegeleisen's program and this. First you will need to calculate as many digits of pi that you will need so use the information found in this thread: [Calculating Pi Java Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21686036/calculating-pi-java-program)

The formula is not "simple", so I won't copy any of the code from the thread, you can see it for yourself.

Once you have used their way of calculation, then use the

> ```
> String pi = String.valueOf([picalcs]).replace(".", "");
> char nDigit = pi.charAt(index);
> ```

with the calculations of pi included in the placeholder of [picalcs] in the code.

If you need more than the amount of digits that a double can store, you will need to create a data storage system. You "could" use an array for storing the double's place values seperately, each holding 16 digits. But you will need to subtract the digits from each other to get more values.

For example if your first index stores: 3.14159 26535 89793
then to get your 2nd index take more values of pi and subtract it from the first to get the next 16 values: 23846 26433 83279 5

This should allow you to get the value of pi for as many digits as you need. Hope this helps, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

try this where the value is the number that user enter and pointer
3.141592653589793115997963468544185161590576171875 if user inter 1 as value
6.28318530717958623199592693708837032318115234375 if user inter 2 as value

```
public static BigDecimal nPi(int value, int pointer) {
    return new BigDecimal(Math.PI  * value).movePointLeft(pointer);
}
```